# I have a list with unicode and int, what's the pythonic way to encode it into utf-8 with loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
list = [u'\u2119', 123, u'other unicode str']
```

if encode unicode directly, get int has no attribute encode error.

if str whole list first, get unicode encode error.

Write `isinstance` condition phrase? ugly...

Or do I have to use error catch phrases?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you'd have to test for types, or catch the exception. I'd use a helper function:

```
def to_utf8_string(v):
    if isinstance(v, unicode):
        return v.encode('utf8')
    return str(v)

map(to_utf8_string, lst)
```

You should really fix this issue earlier however. Build your list out of Unicode string objects *only* (e.g. convert those integers to Unicode strings before appending, if possible).

Comment: I got the data from the net using requests. It's loaded json data. I could only either use error catch or hardcode str to the specific int value.
your helper function is cooler. I'd like to take that. Thanks :D

Comment: Oh, `str(v)`, because they're integers.

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [item.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(item, unicode) else str(item) for item in l]
```

Comment: `else str(item)`.